# How to add text to HTML element after window.location redirects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery I am trying to add text to an HTML element by the `id` after the `window.location` function redirects. Basically to show an error message.

**HTML.ERB**

```
         <p><%= text_field_tag 'birthday', nil, placeholder: 'mm/dd/yyyy'  %></p>
         <p id="birthday"></p>
```

**jQuery/JS**

```
<% content_for :tail do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#leading_health_yes_btn").on('click', function(){
      var x = $("#gender").val();
      var y = $("#hh_size").val();
      var z = $("#birthday").val();
      if ( validateBirthday(z) ){
        $.ajax({ url: "/host_and_post/select?partner=LeadingHealthQuotes&gender="+x+"&hh_size="+y+"&birthday="+z });
      } else {
        window.location = "/sponsors";
        $("#birthday").text("MUST BE mm/dd/yyyy FORMAT");
      }
    });
    function validateBirthday(birthday){
      var regexDate = /^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$/
      return regexDate.test(birthday);
    };
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to do? There's better options

Comment: When you instruct the browser to redirect, it basically "forgets" everything and moves to the next page, so having JS take an action AFTER you redirect won't happen.

What you can do, however, is pass a parameter to the location you're redirecting to and then have your JS take action based on that.

Comment: Is there a way to pass params with the `window.location` function?

Comment: `window.location = '/path?error_message=true'`

Comment: "Is there a way to pass params with the window.location function?" - A lot of. `window.location = 'newUrl.html?var1'+var1+'&var2='+var2`. *Note:* `window.location` is not a function.